# When installing a package, can I give write permission to specific files?

Tags: permissions, package-management

I'm trying to install numpy onto my system. I'm kept from installing the package, however, because I don't have permission to edit certain folders. This "permission block(s)" is the standard safety mechanism that OS developers create to avoid users (like me) from blindly hacking away at some important structure.

I could run `sudo python setup.py install`, and that would override my permission block, but this is risky. If a script contained in a package were unsafe, a call to `sudo` to install the package would overlook any threats.

As opposed to blindly calling `sudo`, can I specifically give an installation permission to install into some *specific* folder?

Comment: what kind of unix, or linux distribution are you using?

Comment: `Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0`

Comment: on a mac, install numpy and scipy with homebrew.  there's a guide here: https://joernhees.de/blog/2014/02/25/scientific-python-on-mac-os-x-10-9-with-homebrew/

Comment: to answer your question, "no.  when you run something  with sudo, you are running it as root".

Comment: by "root", you mean run from the root directory, right? So, `sudo` can never be tailored to only override features of one particular directory?

Comment: no, i mean as the root user, who (ignoring things like selinux) can do whatever they want on the system.  That's what `sudo` is for - running a program as another user (by default, as root).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use virtualenv. virtualenv allows you to install python libraries into a separate directory than the system libraries. You can set the directory to be in a directory where you have write permission (e.g. your home directory).

Alternatively, you can change the group of the files with `chgrp py-installer -R /my/python/packages/directory` and run your installer as that group with `sudo -g py-installer python setup.py` this is a bit more risky as you may end up with incorrect folder permissions if you aren't careful.